# Deleting all zero-opacity elements in Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using the fabricjs `animate` function to change the opacity of text elements on a canvas.
For every frame, I need to check for elements with 0% opacity and remove them with `canvas.remove`.

At the moment, I've come up with this code which I'm running for each fire of `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
canvas.getObjects().filter((obj) => obj.get("opacity") === 0).forEach(canvas.remove)
```

However, when iterating, filtering through the items and running `canvas.remove`, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`.

Here's a simple implementation of this problem (not the actual code):

```js
const canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(document.querySelector("canvas"), { backgroundColor: "black" })

// CODE HERE:
function removalLogic() {
  canvas.getObjects().filter((obj) => obj.get("opacity") === 0).forEach(canvas.remove)
}

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100, height: 100,
  left: 10, top: 20,
  fill: "grey",
})

canvas.add(rect)

rect.animate("opacity", "0", {
    duration: 2500,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: removalLogic,
})
```

```html
<canvas height="512" width="512"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo of this.

Comment: @AmarSingh Sure can. Give me a sec.

Comment: @AmarSingh I've added the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.map()` to iterate over all the objects of `canvas`.
2. Use `canvas.remove(obj)` to remove the object.
3. This statement of yours was incorrect `obj.get("opacity") === 0).forEach`

```js
const canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(document.querySelector("canvas"), { backgroundColor: "black" })

// CODE HERE:
function removalLogic() {
  console.log(canvas.getObjects().length);
  canvas.getObjects().map((obj) => ((obj.get("opacity") == 0)? canvas.remove(obj) :''))
  console.log(canvas.getObjects().length);
  
}

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100, height: 100,
  left: 10, top: 20,
  fill: "grey",
})

canvas.add(rect)

rect.animate("opacity", "0", {
    duration: 2500,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: removalLogic,
})
```

```html
<canvas height="512" width="512"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```